# Jekyll custom placeholders

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to set up a jekyll site that sources its pages from github repository. I can "bring" that repository using the `git submodule` command so that works just fine.

The URL I want to have is:

```
https://example.ld/:version/:language/:page-name
```

For the `:page-name` I can use the `:title` global placeholder.

My folder structure is:

```
posts
posts/1.0
posts/1.0/en
posts/1.0/en/about.md
....
posts/1.0/fr
posts/1.0/fr/about.md
....
```

I tried playing around with the `permalink` option in the configuration but cannot find the right combination to do what I need since `:language` of course does not exist as a placeholder or does `:version`.

Is there a way to define those so that my users can visit the site and view `https://example.ld/1.0/en/about`?

Should I move the `docs` folder under the `_posts` folder?

Any pointers are more than appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Posts should be inside 1.0/en/_posts folder. If they are pages they should be in 1.0/en/ folder directly

Comment: You can use the permalink default for this: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Comment: The problem is that both `1.0` (version) and `en` are not static so that they can be defined in the config. At any given time I might get a new version or a new language. This is why I wrote about custom placeholders

Comment: You are correct... the directory structure from marcanuy seems like the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I will give the folder structure a try